# I want to get a Gpu's name on windows operation system with C++

Tags: c++, windows, gpu

I want to get a Gpu's name,for example AMD Radeon HD4830, I want to get information like "ATI Radeon HD4830".But, I read register and get the information like "ATI Radeon HD 4800 Series".And I Used D3D or OPCL's interface get the information also like "ATI Radeon HD 4800 Series".How can I get a Gpu's name correctly?

Answer (score 0):

I don't remember the exact function you need to call, but you need to use the [`SetupDiXxx` functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff549791.aspx).

Warning: it's a little painful.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this with `c++amp`, if you are in windows:

```
concurrency::accelerator a;
wcout<<a.description; // a.description will contain the details (name if not a emulated accelerator)
```