# How to determine the graphics card between ATI Radeon HD 4850 and ATI Radeon HD4830?

Tags: c++, windows, graphics, ati

The two names is both "ATI Radeon HD 4800 series", when I get them name with WMI or D3D interface.How can I determine them?

Comment: possible duplicate of [I want to get a Gpu's name on windows operation system with C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21248465/i-want-to-get-a-gpus-name-on-windows-operation-system-with-c)

Answer (score 0):

Searching through the [PCI device/vendor list](http://www.pcidatabase.com/reports.php?type=tab-delimeted), there seems to be no difference and also a single "ATI Radeon HD 4800 series" item.

I would suggest though that there has to be a difference in hardware IDs (probably at the subsystem level), which you should be able to access through WMI. You can verify this difference by using Device Manager -> right-click on display adapter -> Properties -> Details -> Select "Hardware IDs" from the drop-dow box.